# Changeset with same fields of target system

Tags: administration, sandbox, change-set, production

what happens if I upload a changeset with the same fields as the target system?

It validated fine but just curious to see what happens...

Does it update the create date?

Comment: You can try it yourself by deploying between two sandboxes. The `createdDate` won't be updated, but the `LastModifiedDate` might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If target system component and source system component are same then there will not be any difference in audit fields (Created/Lastmodified etc.)

Same means, there is no configuration level difference.

These fields change only if there is difference in configuration.

Note: Created date never changes except the sandbox refresh.